# Capture HTML xpath

Tags: html, user-interface, xpath, store, capture

Lets say I have a HTML document with .... It has tables, buttons, divs and lot of components. I want to make a utility which has a GUI. Using this GUI if I click on the button, I should be able to store the button's XPath. 
For example, I have a button(in form of image) "Respond", I click on it and then its XPath //img[@alt='Respond'] should be stored.
Is there any way I can do this, maybe there is a tool to do the above.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firebug's inspect element (FireFox plugin) will show you a breakdown and if (while examining HTML in its console) you right click on a node, context menu "copy xpath" will put it on clipboard.

For example, doing this to post your answer gave:

```
//*[@id="submit-button"]
```

Doing it to "Know someone who can answer..." gives:

```
/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/h2
```

Not sure what your level of integration is, but, Firebug is a starting point.